# How to retrieve images from SQL Database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database

How to retrieve images from SQL Database using C#?

Comment: Google "Display Blob Image C#"

Comment: What's your approach? Why doesn't it work (Exception message, compiler error...)?

Comment: Go ahead,give it a try first, comeback here if you're stuck somewhere!

Comment: Bare in mind sql stores an image as a blob, which is essentially a byte array.  Try and look for examples on converting a byte array to a c# Image object.

Comment: SO won't let me answer with a let me google that for you but if you use your exact question as a google search you get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you need: [an msdn example with code!](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317701) it should at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try by using query string . Here is my code where in query string is used and i fetch images from the database without having to create the any instatnce of that desired image inyour local folder. Hop this helps.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="DisplayImg" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DisplayImg : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string theID;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            theID = context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = DisplayImage(theID);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);

        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        }
    }

    public Stream DisplayImage(string theID)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SERVER"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        string sql = "SELECT Server_image_icon FROM tbl_ServerMaster WHERE server_Code = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", theID);
        connection.Open();
        object theImg = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])theImg);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Just add one line in CS code

UploadImg.ImageUrl = "~/DisplayImg.ashx?id=" + code;

Comment: -1 for not using `using`, not null checking, and returning a `stream` from the method.